# Lag when replacing ViewPager fragment in Navigation Bar over FrameLayout?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, materialdrawer

I am using https://github.com/mikepenz/MaterialDrawer as a library for Drawer, and I am using https://github.com/florent37/MaterialViewPager for View Pager.

The problem that I am facing is that I face a bit of lag(kind of stutter lag) when I click on list item in my drawer and the closing of the drwawer, after which the fragment is replaced over. I face this in a fragment which is a ViewPager over is a fragment.

[image: see the image]

```
   Activity(which has NavBar):

public class mvpAct extends AppCompatActivity {
private RelativeLayout mRelativeLayout;
public static List<Model_Slots> list;
private Drawer result;
private static GetDetails gd;
public static List<Model_Daywise> todayslist_m;
public static List<Model_Daywise> todayslist_t;
public static List<Model_Daywise> todayslist_w;
public static List<Model_Daywise> todayslist_th;
public static List<Model_Daywise> todayslist_fr;
public static List<detailattlist_subcode> detail_att_all = new ArrayList<>();
public static HashMap<String, List<DetailAtten>> hash = new HashMap<>();
public static List<AttendBrief> attendBriefs = null;
public static List<Marks_Model> marks_det;
public static List<PBL_Model> lpbl;

public void setMTWTFLists(final Context ctxt) {
    String mark = new SharedPrefs(ctxt).getMsg("marksdone").trim();
    String att = new SharedPrefs(ctxt).getMsg("ttdone").trim();
    String tt = new SharedPrefs(ctxt).getMsg("attendone").trim();
    Log.d("Done Value", mark + "\t" + att + "\t" + tt);
    if (mark.equals("y") && att.equals("y") && tt.equals("y")) {
        Log.d("Here", "naive");
        try {
            new Thread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    todayslist_m = new MTWTHgetset(ctxt, "monday").getAllCredentials();
                    todayslist_t = new MTWTHgetset(ctxt, "tuesday").getAllCredentials();
                    todayslist_w = new MTWTHgetset(ctxt, "wednesday").getAllCredentials();
                    todayslist_th = new MTWTHgetset(ctxt, "thursday").getAllCredentials();
                    todayslist_fr = new MTWTHgetset(ctxt, "friday").getAllCredentials();
                }
            }).start();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }


}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    if (gd.isAdded())
        getSupportFragmentManager()
                .beginTransaction().remove(gd).commit();
    else super.onBackPressed();

}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.drawer_frame_mvp);
    gd = new GetDetails();
    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.mvp_frame_act, gd).commit();
    }
    try {
        list = new Slots_GetSet(this).getAllCredentials();
        String classnbrs[] = new String[list.size()];
        int r = 0;
        for (Model_Slots ms : list) {
            classnbrs[r++] = ms.getNumber().trim();
        }
        for (int t = 0; t < classnbrs.length; t++) {
            detailattlist_subcode dr = new detailattlist_subcode();
            hash.put(classnbrs[t], new IndivAttGetSet(this, " table_of_" + classnbrs[t]).getAllCredentials());
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    try {
        attendBriefs = new Attend_GetSet(this).getAllCredentials();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    try {
        marks_det = new CBL_Get_Set(this).getAllCredentials();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    try {
        lpbl = new PBL_Get_Set(this).getAllCredentials();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        lpbl = new ArrayList<>();
    }
    try {
        setMTWTFLists(getApplication());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    PrimaryDrawerItem item1 = new PrimaryDrawerItem().withName("Slots").withIdentifier(1);
    SecondaryDrawerItem item2 = new SecondaryDrawerItem().withName("ImageStudentLogin").withIdentifier(2);
    result = new DrawerBuilder()
            .withActivity(this)
            .addDrawerItems(
                    item1,
                    new DividerDrawerItem(),
                    item2,
                    new SecondaryDrawerItem().withName("Setup"),
                    new SecondaryDrawerItem().withName("Daywise")
            )
            .withOnDrawerItemClickListener(new Drawer.OnDrawerItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onItemClick(View view, int position, IDrawerItem drawerItem) {
                    displayView(position);
                    if (result.isDrawerOpen())
                        result.closeDrawer();
                    return true;
                }
            })
            .build();

}


private void displayView(int position) {
    Fragment fragment = null;
    switch (position) {
        case 0:
            String s = getSharedPreferences("sp", Context.MODE_PRIVATE).getString("own", "no");
            if (s.equals("already")) {
                fragment = new Fragment_slots();
            } else if (s.equals("yes")) {
                list = new Slots_GetSet(getApplicationContext()).getAllCredentials();
                fragment = new Fragment_slots();
            } else if (s.equals("no")) {
                fragment = new GetDetails();
            }
            break;
        case 2:
            fragment = new Photo_Stu();
            break;
        case 3:
            fragment = new GetDetails();
            break;
        case 4:
            fragment = MaterialVPFrag.newInstance();
            break;
        default:
            fragment = MaterialVPFrag.newInstance();
            break;
    }
    if (fragment != null) {
        FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
        fm.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.mvp_frame_act, fragment).commit();
    } else {
        Log.e("DrawerActivity", "Error creating fragment");
    }
}


}
```

Fragment(where I face lag(kind of stutter lag) in process of closing the drawer, After which this is replaced over other frame):

```
public class MaterialVPFrag extends Fragment {
private MaterialViewPager mViewPager;

public static MaterialVPFrag newInstance() {
    return new MaterialVPFrag();
}

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.mvp_layout, container, false);

}

@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    mViewPager = (MaterialViewPager) view.findViewById(R.id.materialViewPager);
    mViewPager.getViewPager().setAdapter(new FragmentStatePagerAdapter(getChildFragmentManager()) {
        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            switch (position) {
                case 0:
                    return new RecyclerViewFragment(mvpAct.todayslist_m);
                case 1:
                    return new RecyclerViewFragment(mvpAct.todayslist_t);
                case 2:
                    return new RecyclerViewFragment(mvpAct.todayslist_w);
                case 3:
                    return new RecyclerViewFragment(mvpAct.todayslist_th);
                case 4:
                    return new RecyclerViewFragment(mvpAct.todayslist_fr);
                default:
                    return new RecyclerViewFragment(mvpAct.todayslist_m);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return 5;
        }

        @Override
        public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
            switch (position) {
                case 0:
                    return "Monday";
                case 1:
                    return "Tuesday";
                case 2:
                    return "Wednesday";
                case 3:
                    return "Thursday";
                case 4:
                    return "Friday";
            }
            return "";
        }
    });
    mViewPager.setMaterialViewPagerListener(new MaterialViewPager.Listener() {
        @Override
        public HeaderDesign getHeaderDesign(int page) {
            switch (page) {
                case 0:
   return HeaderDesign.fromColorAndDrawable(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorPrimary), getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.myback));
                case 1:
                    return HeaderDesign.fromColorResAndUrl(
                            R.color.blue,
                            "http://cdn1.tnwcdn.com/wp-content/blogs.dir/1/files/2014/06/wallpaper_51.jpg");
                case 2:
                    return HeaderDesign.fromColorResAndUrl(
                            R.color.cyan,
                            "http://www.droid-life.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/10/lollipop-wallpapers10.jpg");
                case 3:
                    return HeaderDesign.fromColorResAndUrl(
                            R.color.red,
                            "http://www.tothemobile.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/07/original.jpg");
            }
            return null;
        }
    });

    mViewPager.getViewPager().setOffscreenPageLimit(mViewPager.getViewPager().getAdapter().getCount()); //it works without it don't know why!
    mViewPager.getPagerTitleStrip().setViewPager(mViewPager.getViewPager());
    mViewPager.getPagerTitleStrip().setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
    mViewPager.getPagerTitleStrip().setIndicatorColor(Color.RED);
    mViewPager.getPagerTitleStrip().setTabBackground(Color.TRANSPARENT);
    View logo = view.findViewById(R.id.logo_white);
    if (logo != null)
        logo.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                mViewPager.notifyHeaderChanged();

            }
        });

}
}
```

Inner Fragment of ViewPager:

```
public class RecyclerViewFragment extends Fragment {
private RecyclerView mRecyclerView;
public static RecyclerView.Adapter mAdapter;
List<Model_Daywise> list;

public RecyclerViewFragment() {
}

public RecyclerViewFragment(List<Model_Daywise> lis) {
    list = lis;
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_recyclerview, container, false);
}

@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
    mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
    LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
    layoutManager.setOrientation(LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL);
    mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
    mAdapter = new RecyclerViewMaterialAdapter(new CardAdapter_Daywise(list, getActivity()));
    mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
    MaterialViewPagerHelper.registerRecyclerView(getActivity(), mRecyclerView, null);
}
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: have you tried the below delay modification? Or can you provide a sample project showing the problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The latest version of the **MaterialDrawer** comes with a built in delay of 50ms after firing the listener event before closing the drawer itself.

If you have a more complex behavior when switching fragments it makes sense to modify this delay and change it to 150ms or even 250ms.

This can be done via the builder method

```
withDelayOnDrawerClose(int delay)
```

If you want the drawer to close instantly and afterwards switching the fragments you should set the delay to 0ms and add a handler inside your drawer item click listener

```
new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
   @Override
   public void run() {
      //your logic in here
   }
}, yourDelay);
```

Comment: The issue is that there is no lag(stutter) for a simple fragment (for ex. I have 4 EditText and a Button ) but its happening for the above MaterialVPFrag.class(ViewPager in fragment, lag for about 0.8sec ) mentioned above and a fragment which  has RecyclerView in it(lag for about 0.5 sec).

Comment: Hey , See i  did edit the post and added a .gif of the issue.

Comment: have you tried the things i posted in my answer. and add some delay. the thing is the more complicated the fragment is the more time it will take to init. so it will cause lag because the UI is handled on the main thread and this will block the animations too

Comment: Sorry for the delay, I didn't had my laptop with me. I tried using Handler only when position is for that Fragment, now I don't get stutter lag, it just closes after a delay.

Comment: as mentioned you can define the delay directly on the MaterialDrawer which will then delay the closing of the drawer. or you have your own handler to delay the fragment switching. i assume this is the only solution how you can get it fluid. anything missing in the above answer?